# R shiny dataTables with TableTools and other extensions

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny

I am trying to get dataTables TableTools and other extensions working with Shiny. I found a website explaining how to do it:

https://gist.github.com/bearloga/8327428

But I can't get it to work. addResourcePath would not work in my script, so I am sourcing from the full path instead. Even then, it seems like sourcing the DataTables and extensions has no effect, and I only get a basic table without the TableTools or any other extensions working. I know the `tags$script` entries are working because if I make the window small enough, I get the `Screen too small` warning from the HTML below.

Any ideas?

```
#### ui.R
suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("ggplot2", lib.loc="/opt/thirdparty/R/R-3.1.0/lib64/R/library")))
shinyUI = basicPage(
    h1('Diamonds DataTable with TableTools'),
    tagList(
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='/opt/development/tools/webdev/shiny/datatables/DataTables-1.10.0/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js',type='text/javascript'))),
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='/opt/development/tools/webdev/shiny/datatables/TableTools-2.2.1/js/dataTables.tableTools.js',type='text/javascript'))),
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='/opt/development/tools/webdev/shiny/datatables/ColReorder-1.1.1/js/dataTables.colReorder.js',type='text/javascript'))),
    singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='/opt/development/tools/webdev/shiny/datatables/TableTools-2.2.1/css/dataTables.tableTools.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css'))),
    singleton(tags$script(HTML("if (window.innerHeight < 400) alert('Screen too small');")))
    ),
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
)
########################################

### server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
        diamonds[,1:6]
    }, options = list(
           "sDom" = 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
           "oTableTools" = list(
                        "sSwfPath" = "/opt/development/tools/webdev/shiny/datatables/TableTools-2.2.1/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
            "aButtons" = list(
                "copy",
                "print",
                list("sExtends" = "collection",
                     "sButtonText" = "Save",
                     "aButtons" = c("csv","xls")
                )
            )
        )
    )
        )
})
########################################
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link to the correct library versions. Lins to data.table 1.9.4 can be found at http://cdnjs.com/libraries/datatables . Links to tabletools 2.1.5 at http://cdnjs.com/libraries/datatables-tabletools

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
runApp(
  list(ui = basicPage(
    h1('Diamonds DataTable with TableTools'),
    tagList(
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/TableTools.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/css/TableTools.min.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css'))),
      singleton(tags$script(HTML("if (window.innerHeight < 400) alert('Screen too small');")))
    ),
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
  ,server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
      diamonds[,1:6]
    }, options = list(
      "sDom" = 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
      "oTableTools" = list(
        "sSwfPath" = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
        "aButtons" = list(
          "copy",
          "print",
          list("sExtends" = "collection",
               "sButtonText" = "Save",
               "aButtons" = c("csv","xls")
          )
        )
      )
    )
    )
  })
)
```

[image]

Comment: It now shows up although both CSV and Excel go into a `.csv` file.

Comment: apart from the CSV/Excel bit, everything is working. I now moved to another feature, ColReorder and ColVis, which seems to misbehave compared to the examples in the dataTables page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629902/r-shiny-datatables-colvis-behavior