# R shiny DataTables ColVis behavior

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, dt

I got an RStudio Shiny server page with DataTables, and I got TableTools and ColReorder working in the example below, but ColVis (`Show/hide columns` button) is not behaving in the same way as the example in http://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/ :

When clicking the `Show/hide columns` button, the list mixes up with the values in the table underneath, and I cannot make the list disappear by clicking the button again or clicking anywhere else in the page (again, the example in the datatables page behaves correctly).

[image]

Also, I am confused about using `sDom` to order the different elements in the table. I would like the `Show/hide columns` button to be on the top right instead of top left. I am also not sure how to order the different elements in the `sDom` of the table so that after changing the order of the columns, saving to CSV/Excel or hiding some column will give me the new table layout instead of the original one.

Any ideas?

## ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

h1('Diamonds DataTable with TableTools'),
        tagList(
                  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/TableTools.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.1.1/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.0/js/dataTables.colVis.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
                  singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/css/TableTools.min.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css'))),
                  singleton(tags$script(HTML("if (window.innerHeight < 400) alert('Screen too small');")))
                ),
        dataTableOutput("mytable")
      )
)
```

## server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$mytable = renderDataTable({
          diamonds[,1:6]
      }, options = list(
               "sDom" = 'RMDCT<"clear">lfrtip',
               "oTableTools" = list(
                       "sSwfPath" = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                       "aButtons" = list(
                                 "copy",
                                 "print",
                                 list("sExtends" = "collection",
                                                     "sButtonText" = "Save",
                                                     "aButtons" = c("csv","xls")
                                                )
                               )
                     )
             )
    )
})
```

#

Also, there is an issue with column sorting and column reorder:
if one sorts then reorders columns and sorts again, the column headers are flipped around. For example, sort by column depth, then shift column one to the left, then click on header again to sort, now we got header depth with content from the wrong column. See snapshot:

[image]

Comment: You only need the `sDom` option for this library. THen the widget should display correctly. However the widget changes objects in the DOM so you probably need to incorporate calls to `Shiny.unbindAll()` and `Shiny.bindAll()` see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/IE6aQfKXd1I/M_IpbLUUG9AJ

Comment: where should this `Shiny.unbindAll()` and `Shiny.bindAll()` calls should be made relative to the table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some notes:

The current data.table version is incompatible with shiny atm. We need the `1.9.4` version. We then also need the pre `1.1.0` version of `colvis`. Unfortunately this referred to an old version of jQuery that issued a call to `jQuery.browser`. So reference to this `jQuery.browser` needs to be removed it occurs in line 856 to 859. The sDom attribute is also a bit tricky it doesnt appear in the new data.table being replaced by `dom`. Documentation is at http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom. We add the colVis content to a `class="cvclear"` using this snippet `<"cvclear"C>`. Placing it at the top is done by ordering it at the start of the `sDom` statement. This works however we need to right align it. Normally that would be done by adding `align = "right"` to the class but because the class is initiated thru the `sDom` call we instead have to use the HTML5 css `text-align:right`. We add this using `tags$style`.

So the above should allow us to use `colVis` with the current shiny. When shiny upgrades to data.table `1.10.0` then we should be able to use the current `colVis` plugin files and the fixes hopefully wont be necessary.

The following works for me:

**ui.R**

```
# get the colVis js file and delete lines 
library(RCurl)
write(getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openMF/mifosx-community-apps/master/IndividualLendingGeneralJavaScript/resources/libs/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/ColVis/media/js/ColVis.js")
      , file = 'www/colvis.js')
tf <- readLines("www/colvis.js")[-c(856:859)]
write(tf, file = "www/colvis.js")
shinyUI({
  pageWithSidebar(

    h1('Diamonds DataTable with TableTools'),
    tagList(
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/TableTools.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.1.1/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='colvis.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/css/TableTools.min.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css'))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openMF/mifosx-community-apps/master/IndividualLendingGeneralJavaScript/resources/libs/DataTables-1.9.4/extras/ColVis/media/css/ColVis.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css'))),     
      singleton(tags$script(HTML("if (window.innerHeight < 400) alert('Screen too small');"))),
      singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/ColVis/18b52dfdd7255ffe96a92aadc16cadd70e3e174a/media/css/ColVis.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css')))  
      , tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
                        .cvclear{
                         text-align:right}")
        )
      )
    ),
    dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )
})
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytable = renderDataTable({
    diamonds[,1:6]
  }, options = list(
    "sDom" = 'RMD<"cvclear"C><"clear"T>lfrtip',
    "oTableTools" = list(
      "sSwfPath" = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
      "aButtons" = list(
        "copy",
        "print",
        list("sExtends" = "collection",
             "sButtonText" = "Save",
             "aButtons" = c("csv","xls")
        )
      )
    )
  )
  )
}
)
```

You can view the app at:

```
http://128.199.255.233:3838/userApps/john/cvtestapp/
```

[image]

Comment: I got it mostly working now except if one sorts then reorders columns and sorts again, the column headers are flipped around. For example, sort by column `depth`, then shift column one to the left, then click on header again to sort, now we got header `depth` with content from the wrong column... (snapshot in the question)

Comment: The bug in ColReorder and sorting is still there, but I am thinking that this is probably onrelated to this question, so I am going to label this answer as accepted :-)