# R shiny ColVis and datatable search

Tags: regex, r, datatables, shiny

I have TableTools and ColVis working together, but, as it was explained in another post ([R shiny DataTables ColVis behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629902/r-shiny-datatables-colvis-behavior)), when clicking the  Show/hide columns button, the list mixes up with the values in the table underneath, and I cannot make the list disappear.

In that post is mentioned that shiny atm is not compatible with the current data.table version, and I'd like to know if there's any other solution around. Here's my code:

**ui.R**

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinythemes)
 library(ggplot2)

addResourcePath('datatables','\\Users\\Ser\\Downloads\\DataTables-1.10.7\\DataTables-1.10.7\\media')
addResourcePath('tabletools','\\Users\\Ser\\Downloads\\TableTools-2.2.4\\TableTools-2.2.4')

shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("Journal"),


  tags$head(
tags$style(HTML("
  @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Cabin:400,700');
                "))
),

  headerPanel(
h1("List Manager", 
   style = "font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
   font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.1; 
   color: #ad1d28;")),

sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 


#File Upload Manager
fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload'),

tagList(
  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/TableTools.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/js/ZeroClipboard.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
  singleton(tags$head(tags$link(href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/css/TableTools.min.css',rel='stylesheet',type='text/css'))),
  singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src='//cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.0/js/dataTables.colVis.min.js',type='text/javascript'))),
  singleton(tags$script(HTML("if (window.innerHeight < 400) alert('Screen too small');")))
)),

mainPanel(
dataTableOutput("mytable"))

  )))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = renderDataTable({

inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)
read.table(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep='')

  }, options = list(
"dom" = 'TC<"clear">lfrtip',
"colVis" = list(
  "activate"="click",
  "align"="right"),
"oTableTools" = list(
  "sSwfPath" = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
  "aButtons" = list(
    "copy",
    "print",
    list("sExtends" = "collection",
         "sButtonText" = "Save",
         "aButtons" = c("csv","xls")
    )
  )
)
  )
  )
})
```

I also have another question: I'd like to search "<" or ">" values in the searchboxes at the bottom of the table, but I can't make it work. I don't know if I have to add anything to the code so it can be done (such as "regex" or similar).

Comment: In the future, please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the **DT** package instead of hacking the JS libraries by yourself. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme('journal'),
    fluidRow(column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('foo')))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris,
      filter = 'bottom',
      extensions = list(ColVis = list(activate= "click", align = "right")),
      options = list(dom = 'C<"clear">lfrtip')
    )
  }
)
```

See http://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html for more info on DataTables extensions.

Comment: Thanks @Yihui, I'm doing it using DT package but now tabletools options doesn't work (buttons appear but don't copy or save) and the 'filter' option returns this message: Warning in run(timeoutMs) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf –. Don't know if it's better to edit the original post or open a new one. Regards!

Comment: I think you have a column in which all values are NAs. You probably want to remove that column. For the TableTools issue, please see the documentation again: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html

Comment: I have that warning if I include the filter option just when I run the app vía Shiny, but before I upload the file. Perhaps it may be something related with the read.table arguments (read.table(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = "")) but don't know what to do. If removed the filter option there's no problem or warnings and the app runs right.

Comment: The ColVis extension has been removed from DT after v0.1 because it was replaced by the Buttons extension in the DataTables library. You can use the button colvis instead. See -> https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html