# Button which saves renderDataTable output as png from shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Does anyone have an idea how I would go about saving a datatable (DT::renderDataTable) output from shiny as a .png? I.e., I want to create a button, similar to [this button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14843448/4198868)?

E.g., could anyone define a button to save this table as a png:

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(DT)

    DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris) %>% formatStyle(
        'Sepal.Width',
        backgroundColor = styleInterval(3.4, c('gray', 'yellow'))
      )
    })

```
````

Comment: would saving the table data to a tabular format not make sense for your application? I haven't seen many cases of saving a table as an image..

Comment: For inclusion into a static report where I do not want to load and wrangle the data..

Comment: Look into here also, maybe you can just use `DT` library to do all your exporting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510671/r-shiny-datatables-with-tabletools-and-other-extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main task is how to convert the table into PDF format.  [Here are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321127/writing-data-frame-to-pdf-table) [two SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881278/create-a-pdf-table) with answers about how to do that.

Suppose you figure that part out using those reference questions (this isn't shiny related). The way I would approach the next step is by first returning the path to the PDF you create from the function that makes the PDF

```
createPDF <- function(df) {
  # create a pdf
  return(pdf_file)
}
```

And then in Shiny you'd use a `downloadHandler` and you just need to copy that PDF into the filename you supply to `downloadHandler`.  Something like this:

```
### in UI
downloadButton('downloadPdf', 'Download table')

### in server
output$downloadPdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "table.pdf"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      file <- createPDF(df)
      file.copy(file, "table.pdf")  # or something like this
    }
)
```

I haven't tried this but that's what I would try

Comment: Sensible answer and an approach I will investigate. Seems like the Thanks!

Comment: @Nick Did you ever solve this? I'm new to Shiny and can't figure out the function to turn a datatable into a PDF